# Помогите преодолеть ошибку Error:(64, 27) java: unreported exception java.lang.InterruptedException;

Tags: java

Первый раз пишу на java. Программа сканировала айпи подклёченных девайсов и работала в командной строке, но очень захотелось Гуи и кнопочку повторного сканирования. Кнопочка добавилась и весь гугл с мануалами не помогал обойти ошибку

> Error:(64, 27) java: unreported exception
>   java.lang.InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be
>   thrown

хотя судя по поиску должно было работать с решением:

```
try{
   rescan();
}catch(IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

сам код

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.io.File;

public class solution extends JFrame {
    private static String ip_value1 = "192.168.1.1";
    private static String ip_value2 = "1";
    private static String ip_value3 = "ip_value3";
    private static String stb_password = "0";
    private static String root_password = "0";
    private JLabel countLabel;
    private JButton addCrow;

    public solution() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        super("I Find you by IP");

        countLabel = new JLabel("List of Ips:");
        addCrow = new JButton("Scan Ip");
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        //Расставляем компоненты по местам
        add(countLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH); //О размещении компонент поговорим позже

        buttonsPanel.add(addCrow);

        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



        setLocation(300,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20,40);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(ta));
        pack();

        try{ta.read(new FileReader("3.txt"),null);}catch(IOException ioe){}
        initListeners();
    }
    private void initListeners() {
        addCrow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try{
                    rescan();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void readFile(){

        File f = new File("3.txt");
        try{
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while(br.ready()){
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    void rescan() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String grep_ip = "echo "+ root_password + "|sudo -S nmap -sP " + ip_value1 + "/24 | grep -oE '\\b[0-9]{1,3}(\\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\\b' > 1.txt";
        ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", grep_ip);

        procBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process process = procBuilder.start();


        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isrStdout = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
        BufferedReader brStdout = new BufferedReader(isrStdout);

        String line = null;
        while((line = brStdout.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = process.waitFor();

        String grep_ip2 = "echo "+ root_password + "|sudo -S nmap -sP " + ip_value2 + "/24 | grep -oE '\\b[0-9]{1,3}(\\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\\b' > 2.txt";
        ProcessBuilder procBuilder1 = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", grep_ip2);

        procBuilder1.redirectErrorStream(true);


        Process process1 = procBuilder1.start();


        InputStream stdout1 = process1.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isrStdout1 = new InputStreamReader(stdout1);
        BufferedReader brStdout1 = new BufferedReader(isrStdout1);

        String line1 = null;
        while((line1 = brStdout1.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line1);
        }
        System.out.println("get"+line1);

        int exitVal1 = process1.waitFor();
        System.out.println(ip_value2);

        String grep_ip3 = "ifconfig | grep -oE \'inet addr:\\b[0-9]{1,3}(\\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\\b\' > 3.txt";
        ProcessBuilder procBuilder2 = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", grep_ip3);

        procBuilder2.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process process2 = procBuilder2.start();

        InputStream stdout2 = process2.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isrStdout2 = new InputStreamReader(stdout2);
        BufferedReader brStdout2 = new BufferedReader(isrStdout2);

        String line2 = null;
        while((line2 = brStdout2.readLine()) != null) {
            //line2 = line2.replace ("inet addr:", "");
            System.out.println(line2);
        }

        int exitVal2 = process2.waitFor();

        replace_localhost("3.txt");
        replaces("3.txt");
        try{
            rescan();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Scan IPs")) {
                readFile();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }



    public static void read_config() throws IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream(new File("config.ini")));

        ip_value1 = props.getProperty("ip_value1");
        ip_value2 = props.getProperty("ip_value2");
        ip_value3 = props.getProperty("ip_value3");
        stb_password = props.getProperty("stb_password");
        root_password = props.getProperty("root_password");
        System.out.println(ip_value1);
        System.out.println(ip_value2);
        System.out.println(ip_value3);
        System.out.println(stb_password);
        System.out.println(root_password);
        //return ip_value1;
    }
    public static void check_ip_diapasone() throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nmap -sP " + ip_value1 + "/24");
        System.out.println("nmap -sP " + ip_value1 + "/24");
    }

    public static void replaces(String name_file) throws IOException {
        String fileName = name_file;
        String search = "inet addr:";
        String replace = "PC: ";
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        Files.write(path,
                new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset).replace(search, replace)
                        .getBytes(charset));
    }
    public static void replace_localhost(String name_file) throws IOException {
        String fileName = name_file;
        String search = "inet addr:127.0.0.1";
        String replace = "";
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        Files.write(path,
                new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset).replace(search, replace)
                        .getBytes(charset));
    }

    public static String run_command() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ls","-l","/dev");

        procBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);


        Process process = procBuilder.start();

        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isrStdout = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
        BufferedReader brStdout = new BufferedReader(isrStdout);

        String line = null;
        while((line = brStdout.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }


        int exitVal = process.waitFor();
        return "0";
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        read_config();
        check_ip_diapasone();
        String command1 = "nmap -sP " + ip_value1 + "/24";



        String grep_ip = "echo "+ root_password + "|sudo -S nmap -sP " + ip_value1 + "/24 | grep -oE '\\b[0-9]{1,3}(\\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\\b' > 1.txt";
        ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", grep_ip);


        procBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process process = procBuilder.start();

        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isrStdout = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
        BufferedReader brStdout = new BufferedReader(isrStdout);

        String line = null;
        while((line = brStdout.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = process.waitFor();

        String grep_ip2 = "echo "+ root_password + "|sudo -S nmap -sP " + ip_value2 + "/24 | grep -oE '\\b[0-9]{1,3}(\\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\\b' > 2.txt";
        ProcessBuilder procBuilder1 = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", grep_ip2);

        procBuilder1.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process process1 = procBuilder1.start();

        InputStream stdout1 = process1.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isrStdout1 = new InputStreamReader(stdout1);
        BufferedReader brStdout1 = new BufferedReader(isrStdout1);

        String line1 = null;
        while((line1 = brStdout1.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line1);
        }
        System.out.println("get"+line1);

        int exitVal1 = process1.waitFor();
        System.out.println(ip_value2);

            String grep_ip3 = "ifconfig | grep -oE \'inet addr:\\b[0-9]{1,3}(\\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\\b\' > 3.txt";
            ProcessBuilder procBuilder2 = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", grep_ip3);

            procBuilder2.redirectErrorStream(true);

            Process process2 = procBuilder2.start();

            InputStream stdout2 = process2.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isrStdout2 = new InputStreamReader(stdout2);
            BufferedReader brStdout2 = new BufferedReader(isrStdout2);

            String line2 = null;
            while((line2 = brStdout2.readLine()) != null) {
            //line2 = line2.replace ("inet addr:", "");
                System.out.println(line2);
            }


            int exitVal2 = process2.waitFor();

        replace_localhost("3.txt");
        replaces("3.txt");
        new solution().setVisible(true);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В java ошибки делятся на 3 вида: проверяемые(checked exceptions), не проверяемые ( runtime exceptions), ошибки "системного" уровня (errors). Не проверяемые ошибки можно выбрасывать и отлавливать в любом месте. Errors отлавливать обычно не рекомендуется и в большинстве случаев нет смысла так как из программы исправить уже обычно ничего не возможно.

Проверяем к которым относится `java.lang.InterruptedException` требуют что бы методы которые выбрасывают такую ошибку декларировал данный факт в заголовке с помощью ключевого слова `throws`. Пример декларирования есть и у Вас в коде :`solution() throws IOException, InterruptedException    {`.
В случае если Вы вызываете метод выбрасывающий такое исключение то необходимо  вызов обернуть в `try` и обработать проверяемую ошибку в блоке `catch` или так же указать в заголовке метода, что Ваш метод может выбросить подобную ошибку.

Указанная Вами ошибка как раз и говорит о том, что один из методов может выбросить ошибку `java.lang.InterruptedException` которая Вами не обработана и не задекларированная в заголовке метода.

> Error:(64, 27) java: unreported exception java.lang.InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Когда вы пытаетесь "отловить" ошибку с помощью конструкции `catch` необходимо учитывать иерархию между классами ошибок. Конструкция `catch(IOException e)` будет "отлавливать" только ошибки представляемые классом `IOException` и его наследниками. Ошибка [`java.lang.InterruptedException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) в совою очередь наследуется от класса `Exception` и к `IOException` не имеет никакого отношения. Как следствие конструкцией `catch(IOException e)` не будет перехвачена. Можно добавить еще один блок обработки ошибок для `InterruptedException`:

```
try{
   rescan();
}catch(IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}catch (InterruptedException e){
   //код обработки ошибки
}
```